# Is there a way to organize the Cognito forms list into categories?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to organize my Cognito forms into Categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to organize forms into folders is a feature that we are currently working on; you can follow our progress on this feature (or leave comments/suggestions) on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/z2vJRXuG/177-form-folders).